# Ruby code in Puppet templates

Tags: ruby, jetty, puppet

Need some help with a conditional statement I am trying to get going in a template. I am pretty new to coding in ruby like this and I need some help.

Here is what the code looks like.

```
JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty/latest
JETTY_BASE=/opt/web/<app>
TMPDIR=/opt/jetty/temp
JAVA=/usr/java/latest/bin/java
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dspring.profiles.active=<%= scope.lookupvar('wg_<app>::params::env_group') %> -Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j <%= scope.lookupvar('wg_<app>::params::rds_mysql_<app>_password_jetty_default') %> <%= scope.lookupvar('wg_<app>::params::lm_newrelic_agent') %><% if @env_group = ("uat01" or "uat02" or "prod01" or "prod02") then %><%= @ipaddress.gsub(".", "").slice(4,4)%><% end %>"
```

the specific ruby code is:

```
if @env_group = ("uat01" or "uat02" or "prod01" or "prod02") then @ipaddress.gsub(".", "").slice(4,4) end
```

So what I am trying to do is only get the gsub command to run only if it sees the env_group I have stated. I do not want to run at any other point. What I am seeing is that it is still running not mater what the env_group is.

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so what you want is likely to be:

```
if  ["uat01", "uat02", "prod01", "prod02"].include?(@env_group)
```

But to go over your original code:

```
if @env_group = ("uat01" or "uat02" or "prod01" or "prod02") then @ipaddress.gsub(".", "").slice(4,4) end
```

Firstly: when you are testing if something is equal to something, you need to use `==`, not `=` (which just assigns the value to the thing on the left)

```
if (@env_group == "uat01")
```

Secondly: always use `&&` and `||` instead of `and` and `or` (you can google for why if you like, but seriously, always do it)

Thirdly: to or-together multiple comparisons , you'd need to check each one separately against the original value then or it this way:

```
if (@env_group == "uat01") || (@env_group == "uat02") || (@env_group == "prod01") || (@env_group == "prod02")
```

The above is perfectly good interpretation of your code... but my version at the top has fewer characters ;)

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, I will make changes and give it a test.

Answer (score 0):

General tip for templates with long and complex expressions: Untangle them.

```
<% 
env_group = scope.lookupvar('wg_<app>::params::env_group')
password = scope.lookupvar('wg_<app>::params::rds_mysql_<app>_password_jetty_default')
nr_agent = scope.lookupvar('wg_<app>::params::lm_newrelic_agent')
address = if @env_group = ("uat01" or "uat02" or "prod01" or "prod02") 
  @ipaddress.gsub(".", "").slice(4,4)
else
  ''
end 
-%>
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dspring.profiles.active=<%= env_group %> -Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j <%= password %> <%= nr_agent %><%= address %>"
```

...or something along those lines.